# How to avoid “resource cloning” warning in Chef 12, while using resource which name can't be changed

Tags: chef-infra, warnings, deprecated

I know that when I use two resources that have the same name, I might get "deprecated feature used: resource cloning" warning in Chef 12. I could change the name of second resource to avoid resource cloning and get rid of that warning. But what if I can not change resource name? Let's say I have mount at the beginning of my recipe:

```
mount '/mnt/directory' do
  device "//192.168.1.2/something"
  action [:mount]
end
```

and then at the end I have umount:

```
mount '/mnt/directory' do
  device "//192.168.1.2/something"
  action [:umount]
end
```

I know that this is not common to do both mount and umount in one recipe, but that's my unorthodox way of achieving something. While executing this recipe I get warning about *"deprecated feature used: resource cloning"*. How can I avoid that warning while I can not change the name of second resource, since "/mnt/directory" is the name and I can not change the directory on which the umount will take action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every resource in Chef has a so-called *name* property. The value of this property is taken from the name of the resource, but it also can be overwritten using the explicit property name itself.

For the `mount` resource the *name* property is `mount_point`. If you set `mount_point` in your resource, it will not matter how you name the resource:

```
mount 'mount /mnt/directory' do
  mount_point '/mnt/directory'
  device "//192.168.1.2/something"
  action [:mount]
end

mount 'umount /mnt/directory' do
  mount_point '/mnt/directory'
  device "//192.168.1.2/something"
  action [:umount]
end
```